# wpf4, prim4 switching between views in the same region

Tags: wpf, view, prism, mef, switching

I Want to display three views on the same region(list, add and Edit view) on the same region using  wpf with prism, MEF. user have to consult a list and choose an action that enable  the add or edit view. I dont' want to use Popups.
it's a sort of navigation not based on the shell.
I have tried visibility of views but I don't like it.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one view that contains the three views.
After one view is choose, you can replace the active view to selected view.